# Update API on Click - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 and I need to update my mail object via a REST Api when the "SAVE" button is clicked.

The problem is, if I click outside of the input, I want it to cancel (and revert).

my **inbox.compontent.html** file looks like this:

```html
<td class="inbox-data-from hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="pointer" id="{{mailItem.id}}">
     <span *ngIf="!mailItem.editMode" (click)="renameReference(mailItem)">
        {{mailItem.reference}}
     </span>
     <div *ngIf="mailItem.editMode">
       <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="mailItem.reference">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateReference(mailItem)">Save</button>
         </span>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

So in display mode it will show the span, when I click the span it will display the input with mailitem.reference. I don't want to update on change, I want to update when the button is clicked via `updatereference(mailItem)`.

If I put `[(ngModel)]` this will update the model on change, but the problem is, if I click outside of the textbox (and cancel) the model is updated and my display will be updated - but not updated via api (and database), because I have cancelled it.

If I clicked the button it will update the model and everything is fine.

So I need a way to get the input value on the click and then I'll update the model and the API, but I'm not sure how to get the inputs value as its inside a `*ngFor` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second property that is a copy of the first and edit that. Copy it back if saved.

```
class InboxCompontent {

    onEdit(mailItem: IEditableMailItem){
        mailItem.referenceEdit = mailItem.reference;
    }

    updateReference(mailItem: IEditableMailItem){
      mailItem.reference = mailItem.referenceEdit;
      mailItem.referenceEdit = '';
    }

    onCancel(mailItem: IEditableMailItem){
      mailItem.referenceEdit = '';
    }
}

export interface IEditableMailItem{
  reference: string;
  referenceEdit: string;
  id: number;
}
```

Change the `ngModel` binding in the `input` in the template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="mailItem.referenceEdit">
```